# How can openNav and closeNav functions be responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, function, responsive-design, responsive

I'm redesigning my personal portfolio website and would like to have a sidebar containing text be 100% screen-width on mobile (screen size <= 1080px), and 50% screen-width on desktop (screen size > 1080px).
I've been working on writing the JavaScript for the responsive functionality of this and, despite it working at the individual range of those screen sizes, it doesn't react dynamically between the two. Meaning, if `openNav()` is activated via `onclick` at a screen size less than or equal to 1080px my side nav opens to 100% width and, similarly, if `openNav()` is activated at a screen size larger than 1080px my side nave opens to 50% width. However, if I resize a browser window (with the side nav opened) from full desktop width of 2560px down to 1080px or less, the side nav window remains at 50%, rather than responding to the screen size and automatically becoming 100%. Same in reverse.
My typography settings are responsive, as is the navigation.
Sample code from the JavaScript is below.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("svz_side_nav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

function openNav() {
    if (max_width.matches) {
        document.getElementById("svz_side_nav").style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("svz_side_nav").style.width = "50%";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "";
    }
}

var max_width = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1080px)");
```

Comment: you can do this with the `resize` event - but why are you doing it with JS when you can just do it with CSS media queries?

Comment: I've read that using `resize` can be problematic? Also, when I tried to do it in the CSS the sidenav stayed open ... which, since I'm using `onclick` to active the `openNav()` and `closeNav()` functions, I thought it all needed to be within the JS.

Comment: Oh yes, you need JS to open and close the nav on click, but that doesn't mean you have to implement the variable size with JS. You can, for example, use the `click` event to add/remove a class (say `open`), then have the nav always hidden when it doesn't have the `open` class, and visible when it does, with a width that depends (via CSS media queries) on the screen size.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks. I'm rather beginner here with a lot of the event-based things, but I'll look further into this as an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, use CSS for this.  You can use `100vw` to set the width to 100% of the viewport and 50vw to the width to 50% of the viewport width.  Combine these with a media query and you're all set.  Both [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) and [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) have support all the way back to IE9.

Below is a simple implementation that uses `transform: translateX()` to show and hide the menu.

```js
const toggleMenu = () => {
  const menu = document.getElementById('menu')
  menu.style.transform = menu.style.transform === 'translateX(0%)' ? 'translateX(-100%)' : 'translateX(0%)'
}

document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', toggleMenu)
```

```css
#menu {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh; /* set the div height to 100% of the viewport height */
  width: 100vw; /* set the div width to 100% of the viewport width */
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

@media (min-width: 1080px) {
  #menu {
    width: 50vw; /* set the width to 50% of the viewport width on screens of 1080px or greater */
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<button id="menu-toggle">menu</button>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. With some tweaking (e.g. changing the `div` to `#menu` in the `@media screen and (min-width: 1080px))` this seems like it might get me to the right place. I'll adapt to my code and see how it works. Thanks again.